# Eclipse can't import maven project. The selected wizard could not be started

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse Mars with java 1.7.
I can't import Maven project or access the Maven settings from Window/Preference/Maven. Maven plugin is installed and updated.

When I try to import or create Maven project I got this

> The selected wizard could not be started.
>
> Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenImportWizard.
> An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (791).

And when I try to access Maven settings:

> Unable to create the selected preference page.
> An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (791).

Error log below:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (791).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createExecutableExtension(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createWizard(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ImportExportPage$1.createWizard(ImportExportPage.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:142)
    at <unknown class>.<unknown method>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ImportExportPage.getNextPage(ImportExportPage.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:878)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Import.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createExecutableExtension(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createWizard(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ImportExportPage$1.createWizard(ImportExportPage.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.IIndex
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core (790).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$56.run(Workbench.java:2852)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.NoSuchComponentException: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DefaultDownloader
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.Downloader
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.common.ArchetypeArtifactManager

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.archetype.common.ArchetypeArtifactManager
  roleHint: 
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager.<init>(ArchetypeManager.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.newArchetypeManager(MavenPluginActivator.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.start(MavenPluginActivator.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DefaultDownloader
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.Downloader
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.common.ArchetypeArtifactManager

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.archetype.common.ArchetypeArtifactManager
  roleHint: 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.archetype.ArchetypeManager.<init>(ArchetypeManager.java:74)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DefaultDownloader
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.Downloader
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.archetype.common.ArchetypeArtifactManager

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 42 more
```

I work for a company which provide dev toolkit, that's how I got my Eclipse Mars version. The exact same version works on my colleague's machine but not on mine.

We got the same environments variables, same configurations in eclipse.ini, both default workspace, same computer model.

I tried to update all eclipse softwares that are related to Maven or m2e.
I tried to -clean eclipse.

If you have any ideas to solve my issue that would be great because right know I dont know what to do.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you verified the hidden files created with eclipse that maybe stuck in your workspace folder and not in your collegue workspace (e.g .metadata and other files) clean the whole thing) and verify your plugins versions

Comment: Hi,
Both of us tried with the default eclipse workspace.
And every plugins are updated

Comment: With all the files deleted? Even the hidden ones ?

Comment: I just deleted all files in my workspace and try like this but I still face same issue

Comment: You should look how to display a hidden files in a folder according to the OS you are using and be sure that no hidden config file still remain.

Or just to be sure create an other workspace and try the same scenario on it to see if the same problem occurs ? seems clear for you?

Comment: Yes I displayed hidden files and also removed them.
I also tried to create new workspace but it doesnt fix it

Comment: With Eclipse Mars you are five years and 7 releases behind. The stack trace indicates you are using an IBM J9 JRE/JDK (which I guess is also outdated).

Comment: I don't choose the tools we're using.
That doesn't seems to explain why it's working on my colleague's machine

Comment: I understand you are bound to your techstack, but still, is there some valid reason not to use a newer eclipse with an uptodate Maven plugin? You can obviously still develop with JDK 1.7 even then. Other than that my first guess is also looking into the metadata, specifically into the `C:\Users\YourUserName\.eclipse` folder. In addition you can see if you run the same Java version as your colleague, since Eclipse is also Java based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Eclipse Oxygen fixed my issue